# Establishing equality between two functions $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$; $a(x) = x^5 + 1$ and $b(x) = x-4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, polynomials

> Consider the following two polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$:*
> $$
> a(x) = x^5 + 1
> $$
>
> $$
> b(x) = x - 4
> $$
>
> *You may check that $a(0) = b(0), a(1) = b(1), \ldots, a(4) = b(4)$, hence $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are equal functions
> from $\mathbb{Z}_5$ to $\mathbb{Z}_5$.*

Why and how $a(0)=b(0)$ for the above two functions?

Comment: Which book is it?

Comment: @Lano I'm really having hard times understanding this book. The explanations are really vague. It's Pinter's "A book of Abstract Algebra". I thought it's the easiest book in the market.

Comment: I asked you because that "..mainly a difference of viewpoint" is misleading, it contradicts the fact that those two objects are different, so not the same stuff under different lights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$a(0) = (0)^5 + 1 \equiv 1$ mod $5$.

$b(0) =  (0) - 4 = -4 \equiv1$ mod $5$

Remember numbers in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ are the same if they differ by a multiple of 5.

Comment: However, the original text may be confusing - The main point is *not* that the constant term $+1$ of the first is the same as the constant term $-4$ of the second polynomial. In fact $x^5-4=x^5+1$ as *polynomial* in $\mathbb Z_5$ because $-4=1$ here! Rather the essential point is that $x^5$ and $x$  are different polynoials (different degrees!) that take the same values for each input in $\mathbb Z_5$.